# Why $537 a month for $100,000 loan, 5% interest, 30-yr term?

Tags: interest-rate

Apparently, a $100,000 loan with an interest rate of 5 percent and a 30-year term carries a payment of $537 a month.

Why? I've fiddled with the numbers in various ways and can't get $537. For instance, ($100,000 * 1.05) / 30 / 12 = $292 a month.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

```
r = 0.05/12
n = 30*12
s = 100000

(r s)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 536.822
```

Answer (score 10):

> Apparently, a $100,000 loan with an interest rate of 5 percent and a
>   30-year term carries a payment of $537 a month.
>
> Why? I've fiddled with the numbers in various ways and can't get $537.
>   For instance, ($100,000 * 1.05) / 30 / 12 = $292 a month.

The biggest error in your formula is that you assumed that the total interest for the loan would be 100,000*0.05 or $5,000;  but that is closer to the interest for the first year. Your formula spread the payment of the first years interest over the 30 years; and then assumed no interest would be charged for the next 29 years.